# Update one of our Web to Case Forms

Tags: form, web2case

We have a website with different forms and one of our forms needs to be directed to Salesforce. If a customer click the submit button on that form, it should create a case inside our Salesforce Org.

Is this a simple task that can be done or we need a webmaster to accomplish this?

Any idea/suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate the html form can be done in Salesforce by an admin through your setup menu under Web-to-case HTML Generator.

Now you can simply copy/paste the code to your website but you might need someone who understand coding to adapt the style and/or doing some data validation etc.

The code generated will look like this :

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: Please add the following <FORM> element to your page.             -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<form action="https://salesforce_instance" method="POST">

<input type=hidden name="orgid" value="org_id">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://your website url">

<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: These fields are optional debugging elements. Please uncomment    -->
<!--  these lines if you wish to test in debug mode.                          -->
<!--  <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1>                              -->
<!--  <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail"                                  -->
<!--  value="myemail@test.com">                                       -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<label for="name">Contact Name</label><input  id="name" maxlength="80" name="name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="email">Email</label><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="phone">Phone</label><input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="subject">Subject</label><input  id="subject" maxlength="80" name="subject" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="description">Description</label><textarea name="description"></textarea><br>

<input type="hidden"  id="external" name="external" value="1" /><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: N.B. I believe I've seen posts on the need to obfuscate the `orgId` so page scrapers can't discover your SFDC org and spam you to death